could not use @media what should i do?
I am trying to create navbar but @media is not working. What is wrong with that i saw mistake like not using <meta name="view...." or <script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script> what's wrong in my code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebsitesiDeneme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebsitesiDeneme.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:ital,opsz,wght@0,14..32,100..900;1,14..32,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            background-color: #F4F4F4;
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: white;
            height: 80px;
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 16px;
            padding: 0.5rem;
        }

        .navbar-brand {
            font-weight: 500;
            color: green;
            font-size: 24px;
            transition: 0.3s color;
        }

        .login-button {
            background-color: #009970;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            padding: 8px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: 0.3s background-color;
        }

        .login-button:hover {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .navbar-toggler {
            border: none;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
        }

        .navbar-toggler:focus,
        .btn-close:focus {
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: none;
        }

        .nav-link {
            color: #666777;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .nav-link:hover,
        .nav-link.active {
            color: #000;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
            .nav-link::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                width: 0;
                height: 2px;
                background-color: orange;
                visibility: hidden;
                transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }

            .nav-link:hover::before,
            .nav-link.active::before {
                width: 100%;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" href="#">Logo</a>

                <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                    <div class="offcanvas-header">
                        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Logo</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offcanvas-body">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2 active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="login-button">Login</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler pe-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    @RenderBody()

    <hr style="border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #35374c; margin: 20px 0;">

    <footer>
        <div class="container-xxl">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="footer-box" style="border: 1px solid #35374c; border-radius: 5px; padding: 50px 30px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <span style="color: #55565a; font-size:40px">Sosyal Medyadan</span>
                                    <span style="color:#35373c; font-size:40px;">Bizi</span>
                                    <span style="color:#FF5100; font-size:40px;">Takip Edin!</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="right btn bg-light border-1" style="color:rgb(33, 37, 41); border-color:black; border-radius: 30px; padding:15px 12px; width:100px;">
                                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/mimeda/" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
                                        <span>LinkedIn</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="copyrights" style="display:flex; margin-top:10px; justify-content:center; width:100%; align-items:center;">
                            <div class="copy" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-between; align-items:center; width:100%;">
                                <div class="text-copyrights" style="display:block;">
                                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="kisilerinVerilerinKorunmasıVeIslenmesiPolitikası" style="text-decoration:underline; display:block; font-family:'Gilmer-Bold'; color:#35373C; font-size:14px">Kişisel Verilerin Korunması ve İşlenmesi Politikası</a>
                                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="kisiselVerilerinKorunmasiHakkindaAydinlatmaMetni" style="text-decoration:underline; display:block; font-family:'Gilmer-Bold'; color:#35373C; font-size:14px">Kişisel Verilerin Korunması Hakkında Aydınlatma Metni</a>
                                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="veriSahibiIlgiliKisiBasvuruFormu" style="text-decoration:underline; display:block; font-family:'Gilmer-Bold'; color:#35373C; font-size:14px">Veri Sahibi İlgili Kişi Başvuru Formu</a>
                                    <br />
                                    <h4 style="font-size:14px;">Copyright © @DateTime.Now.Year Migros Medya Data</h4>
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;">
                                        <span class="strong">Migros Medya Data</span> web sitesinde her türlü bilgiyi ve görseli değiştirme, <br> düzeltme ve yayınlama hakkını saklı tutar.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <img src="~/Images/anadolu-grubu-logo.png" alt="Anadolu Grubu Logo" class="img-fluid" style="height:60px; vertical-align:middle;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

</body>

</html>


I encountered the same issue while working on .net project. I have .cshtml file there. I use @@media instead of @media for this type of file.
eg: @@media screen and (min-width: 991px)  {
add your code here
}
Hope this will help.
